# Loop through JSON and store in Coredata in swift 3 using Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data, swift3

I'm beginner in IOS developer. I getting the JSON from URL by using Alamofire. I trying to Loop through JSON for store in Coredata.

**JSON:**

```
[{
"stocks": [
           {
           "growth": "29.87",
           "stock_name": "BLA"
           },
           {
           "growth": "28.87",
           "stock_name": "ADVANC"
           }
          ],
"template_name": "stock growth more than 20 in 90 day"
} , ........ 
]
```

**My code**

```
    var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]()


    func loadJSONTemplate() {


        Alamofire.request("http://1xx.xxx.xxx.xx/").responseJSON { response in
            print(response.result)
            if((response.result.value) != nil) {
                if let data = response.result.value {

                    self.arrRes = data as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                }
            }

        for i in 0 ..< self.arrRes.count {

                 var a = self.arrRes[i]

                let templatename = a["template_name"] as? String
                let teststock =  a["stock_name"] as? String
                print(teststock)

        }
```

In coredata, "template_name" has value but, "stock_name" and "growth" is nil
 I don't understand. Please tell me how to solve this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access data from another level of the json. 
So template_name and stocks are peers, but stock_name and growth are in objects which make up the children of stocks.

You need to do something like

```
let templatename = a["template_name"] as? String
let stockArr =  a["stocks"] as? Array

for stock in stockArr {
     let stockName = stock["stock_name"]
     let growth = stock["growth"]
}
```

I would encourage you, once you feel more comfortable, to check out ObjectMapper through Cocoapods. A little on the advance side, but make life a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks you for answer. Please tell me about coredata. if I will store  {
           "growth": "29.87",
           "stock_name": "BLA"
           },
           {
           "growth": "28.87",
           "stock_name": "ADVANC"
           }

Comment: Core data is a database on the phone, so you would parse your json into the database. You create tables and relations between those tables. There's too much code to post for you here but there are plenty of examples across the internet. 

https://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial